# How to change the system_time_zone in mysql?

Tags: mysql, timezone

I verified that my global timezone is set to "+05:30" but the system_time_zone is showing UTC. I want to set system_time_zone to IST or "+05:30". I searched over the internet but couldn't find the solution.

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone;
+--------------------+
| @@global.time_zone |
+--------------------+
| +05:30             |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT @@system_time_zone;
+--------------------+
| @@system_time_zone |
+--------------------+
| UTC                |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I just want to set system_time_zone to IST. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

The system timezone is not related to the database but to the OS. Check the documentation of your OS or share with us which OS you use.

Anyway, I would recommend **always** using UTC for the OS, the database and in your app. Then you can format the date/time in the right timezone at display time, based on the user's preference.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. When you said "The system timezone is not related to the database but to the OS", do you mean it's my server OS? I am using Linode with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have set the timezone to +5:30 using the SSH but the system_time_zone is still set to UTC.

I am thankful for your recommendation to always use UTC, but for the sake of running my test code, I need to set it to IST. I will later use UTC and format the date/time in the right timezone.

Comment: @rk_py yes, to the server OS. More specifically: the OS the mysql server runs on ;) according to the [MySQL 8 docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_system_time_zone) the `system_time_zone` is inherited from the OS and can be overridden by setting the `TZ` environment variable or by using the `--timezone` option of the `mysqld_safe` script. I guess you can also add `timezone=IST` to the `[mysqld]` section of your MySQL configuration file. Hope this helps!